# Adding angular directives from chrome developer tools

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

There is a collision between two libraries I am using, and I'm trying to debug where the problem is, but to do this, it would be of great help if I could change the html directly in the developer tools, then see the effect immediately.  However, I cannot get this to work.  Is this possible?  For instance, I've tried changing `<div> empty </div>` to `<div ng-click="fireMyFunction($event)"> empty </div>` but have had no luck.  Any suggestions welcomed!

Comment: just changing the html in dev tools won't work - it doesn't compile it

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant simply add a directive via the DOM inspector and expect angular to know. Angular first waits until the DOM has completely finished loading, and then it parses/compiles it and creates its "own version" of the DOM with all the angular sugar.

However, What I would do, is try to expose the `$rootScope` to the `window` object (only in this debug instance), try to change the DOM as you are doing it, and then trigger a digest cycle from `window.$rootScope`. This is just a suggestion, it may work, it may not work, but I believe it's worth the try.